# ErrorAction Stop by default in PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell

How can I set in a PowerShell script that all the actions have the property ErrorAction set to Stop?

P.S.: Powershell 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `$ErrorActionPreference` for the script to stop:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
```

edit: As [ivan-mirchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12009086/ivan-mirchev) pointed out, of course this change is not permanet and only active in the runspace where the code is executed. When you open a new Powershell session it will have the default value of `$ErrorAction = 'Continue'`

Comment: I would like to add that this change would be valid only to the current runspace. The next time, when you open a new PowerShell console, it would be again with the default value $ErrorAction = 'Continue'.